# Can Map be performed on a Scala HList

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have done a few implementations of HList now.  One based on Daniel Spiewak's High Wizardry in the Land of Scala talk and another based on a post in Apocalisp blog.  The goal was to have a heterogenous list of which is not heterogenous in the primary type but rather the higher kind.  For example:

```
val requests = Request[String] :: Request[Int] :: HNil
```

I would be able to do a map across the list to perform the request and result in a heterogenous list of the higher kind.  So:

```
requests.map(execute)
```

should equal

```
String :: Int :: HNil
```

Sadly all my attempts have resulted in an HList of Any.  Here is the code from a recent attempt:

```
class Request[+Out](o:Out) {
  type O = Out

  def v:O = o
}

object HList {
  trait Func[-Elem,Out] {
    type Apply[E <: Elem] <: Out
    def apply[N <: Elem](e:N):Apply[N]
  }
  sealed trait HList[Base] {
    type Head <: Base
    type Tail <: HList[Base]
    type Map[Out,F <: Func[Base,Out]] <: HList[Out]
    def head:Head
    def tail:Tail

    def ::[A <: Base](a:A):HList[Base]
    def map[Out,F <: Func[Base,Out]](f:F):Map[Out,F]
  }

  case class HNil[Base]() extends HList[Base] {
    type Head = Nothing
    type Tail = Nothing
    type Map[Out,F <: Func[Base,Out]] = HNil[Out]

    def head = error("Head of an empty HList")
    def tail = error("Head of an empty HList")

    def ::[A <: Base](a:A) = HCons(a,this)
    def map[Out,F <: Func[Base,Out]](f:F) = new HNil[Out]
  }

  case class HCons[Base,A <: Base,B <: HList[Base]](head: A, tail: B) extends HList[Base] {
    type Head = A
    type Tail = B    
    type Map[Out,F <: Func[Base,Out]] = HCons[Out,F#Apply[Head],Tail#Map[Out,F]]

    def ::[C <: Base](c:C) = HCons(c,this)
    def map[Out,F <: Func[Base,Out]](f:F) =
      HCons(f(head),tail.map(f))
  }

  val :: = HCons 
}

object Test extends Application {
  import HList._

  val HNil = new HNil[Request[_]]

  val list = new Request[Int](1) :: new Request[String]("1") :: HNil

  val (a :: b :: HNil) = list
  val y:Request[String] = b

  val results = list.map[Any,Unwrap.type](Unwrap)

  val i:Int = results.head
}

import HList._
object Unwrap extends Func[Request[Any],Any] {
  type Apply[I <: Request[Any]] = I#O
  def apply[N <: Request[Any]](e:N) = null.asInstanceOf[Apply[N]]
}
```

The other attempt was based on the Apocalisp version which uses fold to create a new HList and again it resulted in a HList of Any types.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

The `HList` implementation in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) is rich enough to subsume both `HList` and `KList` functionality. It provides a `map` operation which applies a higher-ranked function, possibly with type-specific cases, across it's elements yielding an appropriately typed `HList` result,

```
import shapeless.Poly._
import shapeless.HList._

// Define a higher-ranked function from Sets to Options
object choose extends (Set ~> Option) {
  def default[T](s : Set[T]) = s.headOption 
}

// An HList of Sets
val sets = Set(1) :: Set("foo") :: HNil

// Map our choose function across it ...
val opts = sets map choose

// The resulting value
opts == Option(1) :: Option("foo") :: HNil
```

Note that although it's the case in the above example there's no requirement that the HList elements share a common outer type constructor, it just has to be the case that the higher-ranked function mapped with has cases for all of the types involved,

```
// size is a higher-ranked function from values of arbitrary type to a 'size'
// which is defined as 1 by default but which has type specific cases for
// Strings and tuples
object size extends (Id ~> Const[Int]#λ) {
  def default[T](t : T) = 1
}
implicit def sizeString = size.λ[String](s => s.length)
implicit def sizeTuple[T, U](implicit st : size.λ[T], su : size.λ[U]) =
  size.λ[(T, U)](t => 1+size(t._1)+size(t._2))

size(23) == 1          // Default
size("foo") == 3       // Type specific case for Strings
size((23, "foo")) == 5 // Type specific case for tuples
```

Now let's map this across an `HList`,

```
val l = 23 :: true :: "foo" :: ("bar", "wibble") :: HNil
val ls = l map size

ls == 1 :: 1 :: 3 :: 10 :: HNil
```

In this case the result type of the function being mapped is constant: it's an Int no matter what the argument type is. Consequently the resulting HList has elements all of the same type, which means that it can usefully be converted to a vanilla list,

```
ls.toList == List(1, 1, 3, 10)
```

Comment: Is the definition of size valid in Shapeless 2.0?  I'm getting an error "object creation impossible, since method apply in trait ~> of type [T](f: shapeless.Id[T])Int is not defined"

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the error @JamesMoore reported is solved by replacing `default` with `apply`

Comment: Anyone know what the current syntax for this is?

Comment: Looks like the current syntax for this required defining a case for each type you can be applied to? See https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#poly-syntax

Comment: Actually I was able to get the current syntax for the higher-ranked function working via `import poly._`. I think the `~>` operator may have been moved into the `poly` package?

Answer (score 3):

what you need is a Klist with type constructor `Request`, and a natural transformation `execute: Request ~> Id`. All of this is detailed in the marvelous type-level programming series of posts at Apocalisp, in particular:

1. [Natural transformation literals](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-7-natural-transformation%C2%A0literals/)
2. [Klist basics](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-8b-klist%C2%A0basics/)

you can checkout the code for the whole series from [Mark Harrah's up repo](https://github.com/harrah/up)

In your case, you'll need something like

```
val reqList = new Request[Int](1) :^: new Request[String]("1") :^: KNil    
val exec = new (Request ~> Id) { def apply[T](reqs: Request[T]): T = reqs.execute }    
val results = reqList down exec
```

the `down` method above is conceptually the same as `map` for a nat transf `M ~> Id`; you also have more general `map` which from a nat transf `M ~> N` and a Klist of kind M yields a KList of kind N.

Comment: I had noticed KLists in XSBT but haven't had time to take a look.  Thanks for the tips.  This issue was driving me craze

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have an example of Map with HList in the recent (October 2016, 5 years after the OP) article "[**Using shapeless' HLists for extra type safety (in Akka Streams)**](https://softwaremill.com//shapeless-hlist-akka-stream/)" from **[Mikołaj Koziarkiewicz](https://github.com/mikolak-net)**.

```
  //glue for the ParserStageDefs
  specs.map(s => Flow[Data].map(s.parser).map(s.processor))
                    .foreach(broadcast ~> _ ~> merge)
```

> The problem lies in the fact that the type information in our specs list is not preserved. Or rather, not preserved the way we want to - the type of the `List` elements is `ParserStageDef[_ >: Int with String]`, so the lowest common supertype for our decorator and incrementer.
>
> The above implies that, when mapping between the parser and processor elements, the compiler has no way to provide the actual type `T` that's used within the given spec.
>
> ### A solution
>
> Here's where HLists come to the rescue. Because they preserve the complete type information for each element, it's possible to define our flow very similarly to our last attempt.
>
> First, let's replace our list with an `HList`:

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist._
import shapeless._
//...

val specs = decorator :: incrementer :: HNil
val specsSize = specs.length.toInt
```

> Now, for the mapping from `ParserStageDefs` into `Flows`, we need to take a different approach, as the `map` for `HList` requires something called P**[oly - a polymorphic function value](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values)**.
>
> Here's how one would look like in our case:

```
import shapeless.PolyDefns.~>
object toFlow extends (ParserStageDef ~> ProcessingFlow) {
  override def apply[T](f: ParserStageDef[T]) = 
                Flow[Data].map(f.parser).map(f.processor)
}
```

> For it to work, we'll also have change `ProcessingFlow` to type `ProcessingFlow[_] = Flow[Data, Data, _]`, since the polymorphic function above expects a higher-kinded type.
>
> Now, our central statement turns out to be:

```
//we convert to a List[ProcessingFlow[_]] for simplicity
specs.map(toFlow).toList.foreach(broadcast ~> _ ~> merge)
```

> and we're all set!